# exe that opens web browser to http://localhost:8088?fgh

Tags: web-applications, file-io, tcp, exe

I downloaded a exe file from a site which was intended to connect to a local usb device and  update its internal firmware. When I ran the exe my default, browser opened to the above location. Is this a executable running as a windows app or a true browser plugin?
Experience tells me that it's a local app loading a web page and communicating via tcp sockets to the server and file IO to the usb device....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than create their own UI via the windowing system's native calls, some programs do their UI through web pages.  They have an internal web server and then just start the system's web browser pointing to that server.

The entire UI is implemented as a local web service.

One major advantage of this is that it is very portable since it can be written in basic C or C++ without any calls to the windowing system and only some basic (very portable) calls to the operating system.